# Dry run Makefile when "Nothing is to be done for 'all'"

Tags: makefile

I would like to dry run Makefile with "make -n", but the project has been compiled, with "Nothing to be done for 'all'" when I use "make -n". How would I do a dry run in this situation ? To do "make clean" is not an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `make -B -n`. The option `-B` is short for `--always-make`, which unconditionally re-runs the makefile. Combining it with the `-n` option simply simulates what the makefile *would* do, which is what it looks like you're going for.